# Multivariate Regression with R using time variables

Tags: r, statistics, cross-validation

I am trying to do a multiple regression analysis with R but I am not sure how to incorporate date values into the regression analysis.

I would like to build a model that predicts the number of conversions from trail member into subscriber using the following variables.

-day_of_trail

-hour_of_trail

-date_of_trail

-country_of_trail

-day_of_subscription

-hour_of_subscription

-days_to_subscribe

I would like to be able to make a estimate of conversion rates from day 1, and have it's accuracy improve as additional subscription information is added.

```
id_of_case  day_of_trail    hour_of_trail   date_of_trail   country_of_trail    day_of_subscription hour_of_subscription    days_to_subscribe
1              1/1/2010          12          Wednesday              US               1/1/2010           15                           0
2              1/2/2010          13          Monday                 US          
3              1/3/2010          12          Tuesday                UK          
4              1/4/2010          14          Thursday               US               1/4/2010           19                           0
5              1/5/2010          15          Wednesday              UK          
6              1/6/2010          12          Friday                 US               1/6/2010           16                           0
7              1/7/2010          9           Wednesday              CA          
8              1/8/2010          13          Thursday               US               1/8/2010           17                           0
9              1/9/2010          12          Wednesday              UK          
10             1/10/2010         15          Friday                 US          
11             1/11/2010         12          Wednesday              US               1/14/2010          16                           3
12             1/12/2010         16          Saturday               CA          
13             1/13/2010         12          Wednesday              UK          
14             1/14/2010         8           Monday                 US               1/15/2010          10                           1
15             1/15/2010         7           Thursday               US          
16             1/16/2010         12          Wednesday              CA          
17             1/17/2010         18          Friday                 CA               1/19/2010          20                           2
18             1/18/2010         19          Tuesday                US          
19             1/19/2010         14          Sunday                 US          
20             1/20/2010         7           Thursday               CA               2/27/2010           9                           38
```

### Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: A question regarding how to build a statistical model is better suited for [crossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: What model/function are you using? As the question stands right now, it's pretty broad.

Comment: I was trying to use the lm() but it doesn't seem to be able to do what I need it to do. Is there a function you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a date component in your regression analysis, the best method is to convert the date from "m/d/y" to a numeric value (days, years, months...). 
Example:

```
day_of_trail =  c("1/1/2010", "1/20/2010")
data = data.frame(day_of_trail)

data$day_of_trail2 <-  as.numeric(as.Date(data$day_of_trail, "%m/%d/%Y") - 
                       min(as.Date(data$day_of_trail, "%m/%d/%Y")))

# Subtracted by the min date to use that as an origin date.
# Also note when subtracting dates, R defaults to number of days
```

Once you get your date in numeric form, you can add it into the regression model and determine if the date has an effect - or if there is a time component effect in the model.

PS: In your case I suspect you would expect a seasonal component to arise. In which case, I would suggest converting `day_of_trail` to what month (as.factor) it occured in, then using that as a component in your regression analysis.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try